# Connection Error while running federated query in BigQuery to Postgres Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to a Postgres SQL instance via a Big Query federated query. As you can see in the code below:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY(
    'project-id.location-id.connection-id', 
    '''SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;''');
```

I am filling out everything as listed in the documentation but I get the following error:

```
Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Connect to PostgreSQL server failed: 
missing "=" after "[text that appears in the project-id portion of the connection id]" 
in connection info string at [1:15]
```

Not really sure why the connection string would want an "=" sign based on Google's documentation.

**NOTE**

The Cloud SQL and Big Query are located inside of the same project and within a location that permit federated queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this form:

```
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("projects/xxxxx-xxxxxx/locations/europe-west1/connections/xxxxxx", "SELECT * FROM data.datos_ingresos_netos")
```

Just substitute the first `xxxx` with your `projectid`, the region with your region and the last `xxxx` with the name you gave to the connection in The bigquery interface (not Cloud SQL info, that goes into the query)