# Google BigQuery Federated Query connection Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to use the Federated Query functionality in BigQuery to query some data from my Cloud SQL Postgres DB.

```
SELECT * FROM 
EXTERNAL_QUERY('{project_name}.US.app_postgres_db', 'select id from posts limit 10')
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Connect to PostgreSQL server failed: missing "=" after "xxxx" in connection info string at [3:1]
```

It is quite similar to the error discussed here, but it was not solved (the word that appears in the quotes is different though):
[Connection Error while running federated query in BigQuery to Postgres Cloud SQL instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585153/connection-error-while-running-federated-query-in-bigquery-to-postgres-cloud-sql)

For reference, I set up the connection in BQ with the following command:

```
bq mk --connection --display_name='App DB' --connection_type='CLOUD_SQL' \
--properties='{"instanceId":"{project-name}:us-central1:postgres-main","database":"main","type":"POSTGRES"}' \
--connection_credential='{"username":"{username}", "password":"{password}"}' \
--project_id={project-name} --location=us app_postgres_db
```

Comment: Can you share how you have set up the connexion in BigQuery?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere -- added the bq command above

Comment: Federated querying is only supported by the Cloud SQL V2 instance with public IP, do you have all these? Is the BQ Connection API enabled? https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/bigqueryconnection.googleapis.com

Comment: Did you try with with fully qualified name of the connection_id: `projects/{project-id}/locations/us/connections/app_postgres_db`?

Comment: @Pentium10 yes and yes. I am in us-central1 so federated query should be supported

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes that results in the same error as well

Comment: I think I know what is happening - The password is multiple words with spaces in between, so I think it is trying to create a connection string and is expecting a "=" after that word in the error message. I realized the word in quotes in the error message is a word in my password. @guillaumeblaquiere any idea how to work around this?

Comment: Interesting case. Let me try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm, it's the password with space   which cause the issue. I tried several things and I found one which works!

Here my original password: `root is root`

Here the password definition in the command line: `"password":"root\\ is\\ root"`

With MySQL no problem with the spaces!!! I will open an issue for that, but here the workaround!

Comment: For information: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191993375